# Disk Utility Requires Admin Password

Tags: osx-mavericks, disk-utility, password-protection

I've been experimenting with Disk Utility lately, trying to create a password protected folder. The strange thing is, I tried to make an image out of this folder called "Chess" and it created successfully. Then I tried it with another folder. This time, it asked me for admin authentication.

[image: 1]

I looked up all the guides on created password protected folders, and none of them mentioned you needed admin access. What is causing it to require administrator authentication?

I even did *chmod 700 (path to folder being imaged)* and *chmod 700 (path to folder that the imaged folder is being saved into* before imaging it. My version is 10.9.5.

(This was originally from Stack Exchange but the people suggested me to put it here.)

Comment: chess has non-standard perms, because it's a 'core' app - check it in Get Info [I have no clue how to do it in terminal]

Comment: ermm… assuming we're talking about the Apple app… otherwise… idk, sorry ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was.

Somehow, on some files of the folder I was trying to image, the System was the owner. I don't know how that happened, but doing ** sudo chown** *(my username)* *(files that I didn't own)* fixed the problem.